# Using Refresh Tokens as the Only External Access Token Given to the Client

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices, fastapi, refresh-token

I'm now implementing a microservices-based architecture. I'm using [FastAPI JWT Auth](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/) in my *UsersService* (the microservice for authentication and authorization) to generate the tokens, and basic JWT validation tools in every other microservice, to ensure that the JWT is legit (including direct access to the *Revoked Tokens Redis* on every one of them).

Currently, I'm using the suggested architecture, with access and refresh tokens.

I'm considering **not exposing the JWT access tokens directly to the clients**, and instead, implementing an API gateway that will convert the refresh tokens to JWTs **on every request**. The JWTs will be passed then to the internal microservices to ensure in-bounds security.

To do this, the client only needs access to the refresh tokens, as the regular JWTs (that will have an extremely short lifespan) are only used to **authenticate and authorize the user internally**. I plan to include all the permissions and scope information inside those JWTs, while the refresh token will only have a `user` payload.

I have 2 questions:

1. Will this architecture work? Is it secure?
2. Are there any recommended python frameworks to implement such an API Gateway?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not secure, as giving out the refresh token to the browser means that the client receiving the refresh token can ask for their own access token without going through your gateway.

A better approach is to only use a session cookie with the client (I assume a browser in your project).

Do take a look at this video
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw](http://alert%E2%80%98OAuth%202%200%E2%80%99;%20//%20The%20impact%20of%20XSS%20on%20OAuth%202%200%20in%20SPAs)

The refresh token is only meant to be used by the client application requesting it and it is a bad practice in general to give it out to other clients/applications.

If you want to just have pure service-to-service communication ,you should look at using the **client credentials flow**, this flow does not use any refresh tokens and does not involve any human user. Perhaps that is what you are after? Then each client can get its own access token.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You suggest the following architecture:
httponly session-id -> API Gateway (internally converting it to refresh token) -> Users API (internally giving the Gateway access token) -> Resources API (validating the access token). I have 2 questions:

1. How is this architecture more secure than my architecture, given that some of my clients are python clients using `requests` for example, and some of them are mobile applications?
2. What is the problem with the fact that the client can use **his own access token** to contact my Resources API?
Thank you!

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: So, in conclusion, just to make sure I understand you correctly, you suggest keeping my architecture the same but giving the client/browser `session_id` (as httponly cookie if it is a browser) instead of refresh token (and all of the refresh token / access token things will just happen in between backend services internally)?

Comment: In your world , what is a client? is it a web browser? or a desktop application or just another service? are there user involved or not? I think that can be helpful if you clarified that.

Comment: In my world the client is the client-side application of the end-user - it can be a browser running a React app, it can be a mobile application, a desktop application, etc. I want to prevent an attacker disguised as client access unauthorized functionality of the backend services, by enforcing him to only access them through the API Gateway and enforcing in-bounds usage of access tokens (in case the attacker gets direct access to the backend services by getting access to the private network).

Comment: If you are developing a new system, then using the approach of the BFF pattern is a good approach, where you give out the simplest and most secure of your options and that is a cookie, this is a well understood concept and how to properly protect using various techiniques. giving tokens to the clients directly might give you more complexty and headaches.

Comment: see https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/  and https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf

Comment: I read about it and it sounds exactly like what I wanted. But just to be clear, the internal interaction between the BFF and the internal services should be with JWTs created by refresh token (which isn't given to the client, just saved in the session in the BFF service), right?

Comment: Yes, the BFF is in charge of dealing with the refresh tokens in the backend, safe!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will create the BFF, Users API, and Resources API accordingly :)

Comment: I'll appreciate it if you can check this question of mine, related to this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456225/will-this-authentication-authorization-architecture-for-microservices-work