# Will this Authentication/Authorization Architecture for Microservices work?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices, refresh-token

I'm designing a microservices-based architecture. The architecture should support multiple devices accessing the API.

In order to secure the internal *Resource API*s, I wanted to implement authentication and authorization based on JWTs and Refresh Tokens.

My requirements are:

1. Preventing an attacker from using XSS to steal the user's token
2. Preventing CSRF attacks
3. In-bounds security: even if the attacker can send requests to the internal *Resource API*s, he can't do anything without a signed JWT
4. Managing users (Authentication and Permissions) via a single internal *Users API*
5. The tokens can be revoked at any time
6. Support Multi-Factor Authentication via TOPT

This is what I came with:

[image]

Few details:

1. The JWTs are really short-lived (30 seconds)
2. The *Internal API Gateway* will include an endpoint (login) for converting username, password, and TOPT passcode to a new refresh token via the *Users API*.

Will this architecture actually work? will it be secure?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you use cookies for both the mobile and browser? that would simplify things?

Comment: Hey, it can, I can consider implementing it that way. Does it have security benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokens are actually harder to secure from JavaScript than pure cookies that we have several mature ways to protect from JavaScript (like Secure, HttpOnly, SameSite...).

I think you should keep your architecture less complex by using the same technique everywhere for both mobile and browsers. As both types are considered to be insecure public clients.

also, a hint, it can be interesting for you to explore how existing application deal with this using a tool like Fiddler to capture all the mobile traffic and explore how they deal with login, session and signout.

see https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforios

Comment: Thank you very much! I will consider it.